# ios 7 UITabbar more tabs are not appearing in more screen?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, xcode5

I developed one iOS app before launching iOS 7. And this app contain one `UITabbarController` with 8 tabs. Now, when I am running this app in Xcode 5 then all tabs in more tab screen are not appearing. So please suggest any suitable answer.

Thanks in advance.